# Meanings of "back up" in American English

Tags: word-usage, american-english, phrasal-verbs

The Macmillan Dictionary entry for *[back up](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/back-up)* reads

> 4. [intransitive/transitive] if traffic backs up, or if it is backed up, the vehicles are in a long line and waiting to continue moving
>
> > 4a. if a toilet, sink, or drain backs up, or if it is backed up, water cannot flow through it because something is blocking it
> >
> > 4b. if a system backs up, or if it is backed up, it has slowed down or stopped working because there is too much of something for it to deal with

Here are these meanings common in American English? Are they used in daily life conversations?

Comment: I'm an American in NYC, and those usages are quite common.

Comment: @Jeff Zeitlin ,is it common to use:  We're all backed up at work right now. (We're very busy. We have too much work!)

Comment: Yes, those usages are _quite_ common.

Comment: I have quoted the entry; please do not expect community members to open a separate website and then search for the relevant text. Additionally, it would help if you indicated how you've attempted to research this, even something as simple as searching for "sink backed up" or "traffic backed up" on the web.

Comment: No @Jeff Zeitlin I meant the new sentence:: We're all backed up at work right now. (We're very busy. We have too much work!) [Is this usage,in this context common?]

Comment: _Yes, those usages are **quite** common._ There is nothing unusual about that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Using 'backed up' to mean something is experiencing a blockage or bottleneck is very common.

Take a look at [Google's Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sink%20backed%20up%2Ctraffic%20backed%20up%2Cwork%20backed%20up%2Csystem%20backed%20up%2Ctoilet%20backed%20up&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csink%20backed%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctraffic%20backed%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwork%20backed%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csystem%20backed%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctoilet%20backed%20up%3B%2Cc0) for some indication of popularity.

Some of these examples (eg 'work backed up') could mean 'backed up' in the sense of 'data saved in duplicate in case of computer errors'. However, as the comments show, the simple answer to you question is 'yes'.